# Replace function will not compile

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I am trying to use a replace function in vba and it will not compile.
I have the following code

```
Sub Example1()

Dim Str As String
strNew = "xxyy"
strNew = Replace(strNew, "y", "z")

End Sub
```

The error I get is "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.
This methodology is everywhere on the forums and this is exactly as per the microsoft documents but it will not work. I even copied this from another post just to make sure it wasn't my typing.

Comment: Do you have a subroutine named `Replace`?

Comment: Also, don't use `Str` as a variable, that shadows the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) function.

Comment: You `Dim Str` but you use `strNew`

Comment: Just remove that `Dim` line as it's either in error at worst or superfluous at best and rerun.

Comment: @JNevill `Dim` is never superfluous. Every module should start with `option Explicit`, that would reduce the number of bad questions on SO.

Comment: It's absolutely 100% superfluous here since it's declaring a string variable that is never used.

Comment: Better: `Dim strNew As String`. Declare the variable that's actually used. Even better, avoid using Hungarian notation.

Comment: If you have your own function named `Replace`, you can specify which `Replace` you're trying to call by adding the parent. In this case `VBA.Replace()`. The better solution is to rename your own function to not overlap with existing ones, but if you really want the name, then make sure to always specify the parent.

Comment: What @Toddleson said. If that does not help, have a look at Tools - References. If something says Error there, you have found the culprit. And also - do not listen to the "Remove Dim" advice.